# How to install a Kingston SSDNow V100 128, concerned about boot order and partition alignment?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ssd

In order to install Win 7, I should unplug my HDD, plug in the SSD,boot with Windows 7 disk, install in the SSD, Reconnect the HDD and wipe the system drive.

Please  tell me if I am doing it correct or not.

Now some questions.

1. Once the HDD is reconnected,will it boot to Win 7 from SSD or Win7(+Ubuntu) from HDD
2. Windows 7/Vista automatically set up alignment on SSD. So I do not need to worry here,but I would be installing Ubuntu 10.10 (or probably wait for 11.04),then I have to manually set up alignment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:  It depends on what your motherboard is set to boot from from first.  You'll need to go to the bios screen (before windows starts) and verify that the ssd is first on the boot device order.

you may also have some luck with running "fixboot" from the repair console. It scans all accessible drives for boot-able windows and helps put them in the bootloader.

2: Using gparted (ubuntu's partition manager), you can trick it into aligning correctly. Works best from the live cd since the partition manager is available on the disk without needing to reboot.

See this [article](http://en.dogeno.us/2010/01/use-gparted-to-align-partitions-on-a-ssd-hard-drive-for-better-performance/) which refers to this [forum post](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?60340-cloning-HDD-gt-SSD-*with-alignment*-quickly-with-GParted).

Comment: Thanks ! It helped :) Using the SSD for more than 2 weeks,now and really impressed by it.